# Appsflyer log Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.appsflyer.internal.b>: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:

Tags: android

In the android studio Logcat, I can see some logs:

```
AppsFlyer_5.0.0: Cannot verify existence of our InstanceID Listener Service in the manifest. Please refer to documentation.

Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.appsflyer.internal.b>: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: 
    at java.lang.Object com.appsflyer.internal.b.ˋ(int, int, char) (:-1)
    at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore$b.run() (:3335)
    at void com.appsflyer.AFExecutor$4$3.run() (:31)
```

appsflyer SDK version: 5.0.0
I can't find anything event on AF dashboard，

change appsflyer version to 4.8.17, the app can work.

My code :

```
 AppsFlyerLib appsFlyerLib = AppsFlyerLib.getInstance();
      appsFlyerLib.setDebugLog(KwikBuildConfig.DEBUG);

      appsFlyerLib.setCollectAndroidID(true);
      appsFlyerLib.setCollectIMEI(false);
      //      appsFlyerLib.setAndroidIdData(KwaiConfig.getDeviceId());

      appsFlyerLib.setCustomerUserId(Me.get().getId());

      AppsFlyerConversionListener conversionDataListener = new AppsFlyerConversionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConversionDataSuccess(Map<String, Object> map) {}

        @Override
        public void onConversionDataFail(String s) {
          
        }

        @Override
        public void onAppOpenAttribution(Map<String, String> conversionData) {
         
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttributionFailure(String errorMessage) {
         
        }
      };

      appsFlyerLib.init(APPS_FLYER_KEY, conversionDataListener, context);
      appsFlyerLib.startTracking((Application) context);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing resource files

If you are using Android SDK 5.0.0 and above, make sure that in the APK file, in addition to the classes.dex and resources files, you also have the folder `com` > `appsflyer` > `internal` with files `a.` and `b.` inside.

If those files are missing, the SDK can't make network requests to our server.

Check that you have the required files by opening your APK in Android Studio. See the following screenshot for reference.

https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-Android-SDK-integration-for-developers#integration-missing-resource-files

Comment: first thank u very much.  in the `application/build.gradle` , i am used 

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'com/**'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first thank u very much.

in the `application/build.gradle` , i am used

```
packagingOptions {
   exclude 'com/**'
}
```

so delete the code will be work